# How to get the scan duration below 1 sec with Arduino BLE?

Tags: esp32, ble, cpp

I want to scan continuously for other Bluetooth devices with my ESP32 using BLE. The `scan` method only accepts integers larger than 0, such as `scan->start(1, false)`. However I want the results to be more "responsive" and a 1-second scanning duration is too long. This is my sample code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BLEAdvertisedDevice.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEScan.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const int PIN = 2;
const int CUTOFF = -40;
BLEScan* scan;

#define SERVICE_UUID "f5aeb701-4395-4387-b8d4-e1f542b05151"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "b2bd617f-6f78-45e7-bfdd-3edf29a5661a"

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN, OUTPUT);
  BLEDevice::init("ESP32 GrooveBrick");
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
    CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE);
  pService->start();
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  scan = BLEDevice::getScan();
  scan->setActiveScan(true);
  /*!< Scan interval. This is defined as the time interval from
    when the Controller started its last LE scan until it begins the subsequent LE scan.
    Range: 0x0004 to 0x4000 Default: 0x0010 (10 ms)
    Time = N * 0.625 msec
    Time Range: 2.5 msec to 10.24 seconds*/
  scan->setInterval(100); //interval (how often there is a scan)
  /*!< Scan window. The duration of the LE scan. LE_Scan_Window
    shall be less than or equal to LE_Scan_Interval
    Range: 0x0004 to 0x4000 Default: 0x0010 (10 ms)
    Time = N * 0.625 msec
    Time Range: 2.5 msec to 10240 msec */
  scan->setWindow(99);  // window (how long the scans are) must be <= interval
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
}

void loop() {
  BLEScanResults results = scan->start(1, true);
  int best = CUTOFF;

  std::cout << "Scanning!" << "\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < results.getCount(); i++) {
    BLEAdvertisedDevice device = results.getDevice(i);
    std::cout << "Found BT-device: " << device.getName() << " RSSI: " << std::to_string(device.getRSSI()) << "\n";
    int rssi = device.getRSSI();
    if (rssi > best) {
      best = rssi;
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(PIN, best > CUTOFF ? HIGH : LOW);
  scan->clearResults();   // delete results fromBLEScan buffer to release memory
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, IIRC I never solved this.. sry

Answer (score 2):

You can't using the callback from that function, but what you can do is add you own callback that will receive every new radio event.

Add this to your init code:

```
BLEDevice::setCustomGapHandler(custom_handler);
```

and this before it:

```
static void it_gap_cb(esp_gap_ble_cb_event_t event, esp_ble_gap_cb_param_t *param)
{
    switch (event)
    {
        case ESP_GAP_BLE_SCAN_RESULT_EVT:
            if (param->scan_rst.search_evt == ESP_GAP_SEARCH_INQ_RES_EVT)
            {
                // This event is triggered every time a new device is found, and contains the advertised data.
                // We should avoid processing or printing anything here to avoid hardware congestion
                // log_i("ESP_GAP_BLE_SCAN_RESULT_EVT");

                if (param->scan_rst.ble_adv != NULL)
                {
                    //this makes sure that there is data to be processed
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            // log_i("Event %d unhandled", event);
            break;
    }
}
```